# How can I configure UFW to allow VNC access to my computer from a specific IP address?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, vnc

How can I configure UFW to allow VNC access to my computer from a specific IP address?

Hello,

I am connecting from another local device to my laptop. How can I configure the UFW to let my specific device through?

Vesa

Ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/ufw-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands

This would be
`sudo ufw allow from 1.2.3.4 to any port 5900`

Comment: Yes, just found the same solution. I had been making a simple mistake in my previous inputs. Thanks, correct answer.

Comment: Depending on your use case, note that "from any to any"  covers all incoming addresses and "from 192.168.1.0/24 to any" allows a specific subnet.